# Stack_overflow with tree traversal

Tags: recursion, tree, functional-programming, ocaml

My tree is defined as below: (It's just for better understanding, my data type is much more complicated.)

```
  type tree = {
    mutable value : int;
    mutable nodes : tree list
  }
```

I need to find a sequence of 0 and 1, as shown below:

```
    1  
    |
  0 0
  \ /
   1
   |
   1
```

The output will be the root and the sequence of 0 and 1. Here is my code to do that: (I assumed that the sequence will only appear when the nodes (tree list) of the tree which have value 0 has only one element, but i need to change that because it's not necessary.)

```
let rec getSequence tree = 
  match tree.value with
  | 0 ->
if (List.length tree.nodes) = 1 then
  let nextTree = List.hd tree.nodes in
  match nextTree.value with
  | 1 -> 
    nextTree.nodes <- [];
    tree.nodes <- [nextTree];
    [tree]
  | 0 -> List.concat (List.map (fun t -> getSequence t) nextTree.nodes)
else List.concat (List.map (fun t -> getSequence t) tree.nodes)
  | 1 -> List.concat (List.map (fun t -> getSequence t) tree.nodes)
```

For some reason when i execute the code the exception Stack_overflow is raised. Anyone could help me?

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted the right snippet? Your code, as you gave it, does not type check.

Comment: I don't see any obvious flaw in the code. Perhaps you could show the input that causes the problem.

Comment: I understand neither the diagram (could you give an example of input and output?), nor the code (why is mutation happening?). Is it possible that you created a cyclic value using mutation (a tree that points to itself through one of its children)? Running any non-tail recursive procedure on a cyclic value is a sure way to blow the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
let nextTree = List.hd tree.nodes in
nextTree.nodes <- [];
```

Is not equivalent as:

```
tree.nodes<-(List.tl tree.nodes);
```

With the first, tree doesn't change of list that it contains so you always do the same operation and you have a stack_overflow

Answer (score 0):

I tried it but get no exception with your sample input. I'm guessing you only get the Stack_overflow exception with a much bigger (particularly deeper) input.

Here are some options:

1. Increase the stack size:

   export OCAMLRUNPARAM='l=64M' # or whatever
2. Rewrite your function to be tail recursive, so it won't need very much stack space. You can do that by passing your state as arguments.

Other suggestions:

- Use pattern matching instead of `List.length` and `List.hd`.
- If you go with 2., you can avoid the `List.concat` too.